# Object becomes undefined when Appending property

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Good Morning Stack Overflow, I have some weird bug that I have been finding in my code. I am building a simple contact app from this course, I have 4 files

App.jsx:

```
 import React from "react";
import Card from "./Card.jsx";
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="heading">My Contacts</h1>
      <Card id="0" />
      <Card id="1" />
      <Card id="2" />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Card.jsx:

```
function Card(props){
  // console.log(contacts[props.id].name);
   return ( <div className="card">
    <div className="top">
      <h2 className="name">{contacts[props.id].name}</h2>
      <img className="circle-img"
        src={contacts[props.id].imgURL}
        alt="avatar_img"
      />
    </div>
    <div className="bottom">
      <Details id={props.id} infoType="name" />
      {/* <Details infoType="email" /> */}
    </div>
  </div> )
}
```

Details.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import contacts from "../contacts.js";

function Details(props){

var type = props.infoType;

console.log(props.infoType)
console.log(contacts[props.id]);
console.log(contacts[props.id].name);
console.log(contacts[props.id].infoDetails)
console.log(contacts[props.id].type);


 return (
<p className="info">fds</p>

 )
} 

export default Details;
```

Also here is my contact.js object file for reference:

```
const contacts = [
  {
    name: "Beyonce",
    imgURL:
      "https://blackhistorywall.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/picture-device-independent-bitmap-119.jpg",
    phone: "+123 456 789",
    email: "b@beyonce.com"
  },
  {
    name: "Jack Bauer",
    imgURL:
      "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/625247595825246208/X3XLea04_400x400.jpg",
    phone: "+987 654 321",
    email: "jack@nowhere.com"
  },
  {
    name: "Chuck Norris",
    imgURL:
      "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e3/94/47/e39447de921955826b1e498ccf9a39af.png",
    phone: "+918 372 574",
    email: "gmail@chucknorris.com"
  }
];
export default contacts;
```

What happens is when the first 3 console.log() statements get called in Details.jsx they all log exactly what they should.
The first logs the infoType which is "name" just like we want.
The second logs the id, which works.
The third logs the object of the name via the index of the contacts array from the id we got passed over
But as soon as I get to these 4th and 5th console.log() statements it just can't read the object anymore and gets read as "undefined";

I thought it would be pretty easy since we selected the contact from the array with the ID index we passed over but I cant just append the infoType such as "name" by doing contacts[props.id].props.infoType or store infoType as a varriable such as infoDetails than just append that such as contacts[props.id].infoDetail. it just seems to break and turn into an Undefined object. Any help would be great as I am very confused to what is going on here

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?  Are you trying to log your props that you passed to your `<Details  />` component or do you want to append the props to your array?

Comment: There are two props being passed from <Details />  the id of the contact so props.id and then the infoType either phone or email. 
if I pass <Details id={props.id} infoType="name"> I get the id and the name, and I can use contacts[props.id] to get the entire object I can use contacts[props.id].name to get the specific objects name. but then I cant for example do contacts[props.id].props.infoType to get the name it goes undefined. and I cant put inoType into a var such as infoDetials and do contacts[props.id].infoDetails it still goes undefined

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by instead of appending it with dot notation such as

```
contacts[props.id].varWithPropertyNeeded
```

but instead rather using backet syntax

```
contacts[props.id][varWithPropertyNeeded]
```

Comment: Ah I really don't get what you were trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

Your contact object is:

```
{
    name: "Beyonce",
    imgURL:
      "https://blackhistorywall.files.wordpress.com/2010/02/picture-device-independent-bitmap-119.jpg",
    phone: "+123 456 789",
    email: "b@beyonce.com"
}
```

So your `console.log` work as long as you try to read properties that are defined: `name`, `imgURL`, `phone` and `email`.

That's why the first three console works (specially the third one) and the two last ones don't.

Comment: Right I am trying to pass over a prop that has the property that I want, so infoType has "name" stored so shouldn't I just be able to set infoType to like name, imgURL, phone, or email and then read that property?

Comment: Not sure to understand your problem though. infoDetails is never set, so you cannot access it.

Comment: i had props.infoType stored as infoDetails so it would be like contacts[props.id].infoDetails but even as contacts[props.id].props.infoType, they both go undefined

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve still but you are trying to log a value from your array that doesn't exist. If you want to log the props you passed to this component, simply log the props without trying to access the array like this:

```
function Details(props) {
  const { id, infoType } = props;

  console.log(contacts[id]);
  console.log(contacts[id].name);
  console.log(id);
  console.log(infoType);

  return ( <p className="info">fds</p> )
}
```

If you are looking to append your props to your array I'll update my answer.